# MySQL - Find start and end of blocks of consecutive rows with the same value

Tags: mysql

I need to extract and migrate values from one table to another. the source table contains sumarized values for a specific effectivity date. If a value is changed, a new line is written if something is changed on the component values with the data valid starting at this effective date.

| source_id | entity_id | effective_date | component_1 | component_2 | component_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| int(ai) | int | date | int | int | int |
| 1 | 159 | 2020-01-01 | 100 | 0 | 90 |
| 2 | 159 | 2020-05-01 | 140 | 50 | 90 |
| 3 | 159 | 2020-08-01 | 0 | 30 | 90 |
| 5 | 159 | 2020-12-01 | 0 | 30 | 50 |

i need now migrate this data to a new table like this. the goal is that selecting data for a given month the result is the valid data for this month is given.

| id | source_id | entity_id | startdate | enddate | component_type | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| int(ai) | int | int | date | date | int | int |

each row represents a value for a component valid for a period of month.
I now run the insert update for each effective month by setting it as a parameter.
I insert value changes as new rows to the table an prevent duplicates by using a unique key (entity_id,effective_date,component_type)

```
    SET @effective_date = '2020-01-01';
    INSERT INTO component_final 
       select NULL,
              source_id, 
              entity_id,
              effective_date,
              NULL,
              1,
              component_1 
       FROM component_source 
       WHERE effective_date = @effective_date 
       AND component_1>0;
```

after migrating the first row it should be that result

| id | source_id | entity_id | startdate | enddate | component_type | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 159 | 2020-01-01 | NULL | 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 1 | 159 | 2020-01-01 | NULL | 3 | 90 |

```
    SET @effective_date = '2020-05-01';
    INSERT INTO component_final 
       select NULL,
              source_id, 
              entity_id,
              effective_date,
              NULL,
              1,
              component_1 
       FROM component_source 
       WHERE effective_date = @effective_date 
       AND component_1>0;
```

after migrating the second row it should be that result

| id | source_id | entity_id | startdate | enddate | component_type | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 159 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-04-30 | 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 1 | 159 | 2020-01-01 | NULL | 3 | 90 |
| 3 | 2 | 159 | 2020-05-01 | NULL | 1 | 140 |
| 4 | 2 | 159 | 2020-05-01 | NULL | 2 | 50 |

so if there is a value change in the future an end date has to be set.

I'm not able to do the second step, updating the data, if the component is changed in the future.
Maybe it is possible to have it as triggers after insert new row with same entity and component - but I was not able to make it work.

Some ideas? I want to handle this only inside of the `MySQL`.

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: You cannot both insert new rows and update existing rows in one query. Perform your action in stored procedure. Or use 2 queries.

Comment: Why do you want to migrate line-by-line, not the whole data array in one query?

Comment: @Akina if i would know how to do it - i would. the example above should show what is given and what should be the result.

Comment: As I pointed out in my answer, I think you could further simplify your example by dropping the `entity_id` and considering only a single component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the column `enddate` in the table `component_final`, because it's value depends on other values in the same table:

```
SELECT
   id,
   source_id,
   entity_id,
   startdate,
   (  SELECT DATE_ADD(MIN(cf2.startdate),INTERVAL -1 DAY) 
      FROM component_final cf2 
      WHERE cf2.startdate > cf1.startdate
        AND cf2.source_id = cf1.source_id
        AND cf2.entity_id = cf1.entity_id
   ) as enddate,
   component_type,
   value
FROM component_final cf1;
```

Comment: mhm, how i process then the third source_id where the component_1 stops?
as i understand your idea to only insert changed values and also insert 0 values for removed components?
i tried your statement but the enddate column is always NULL

Comment: If you provide a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0), than i can have a look with your data(sample).

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the core issue is how to find the `source_id`s where a component changes (0 means a removal, so we don't want these entries in the result) and how to assign the respective end dates at the same time. For the sake of illustration I simplify your example a bit:

- There is only one `component_type` (I take into account that there might then be consecutive entries with unchanged value)
- there is only one `entity_id`, so we can ignore it

It should be easy to extend this simpler version to your real-world problem.

To this is an example input:

| source_id | effective_date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 100 |
| 2 | 2020-01-03 | 100 |
| 3 | 2020-01-05 | 80 |
| 4 | 2020-01-10 | 0 |
| 5 | 2020-01-12 | 30 |

I would expect the following output to be generated:

| source_id | start_date | end_date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-04 | 100 |
| 3 | 2020-01-05 | 2020-01-09 | 80 |
| 5 | 2020-01-12 | NULL | 30 |

You can achieve this with one query by joing each row with the previous one to check if the value has changed (find the start dates of periods) and the first row that is in the future and has a different value (find the start of the next period). If there is no previous row, it is considered a start as well. If there is no later update of the value, we have no `end_date`.

```
SELECT
  main.source_id,
  main.effective_date as start_date,
  DATE_SUB(next_start.effective_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) as end_date,
  main.value
FROM source main
  LEFT JOIN source prev ON prev.effective_date = (
    SELECT MAX(effective_date)
    FROM source
    WHERE effective_date < main.effective_date
  )
  LEFT JOIN source next_start ON next_start.effective_date = (
    SELECT MIN(effective_date)
    FROM source
    WHERE effective_date > main.effective_date AND value <> main.value
  )
WHERE
  ISNULL(prev.source_id) OR prev.value <> main.value
  AND main.value <> 0
ORDER BY main.source_id
```

As I said: This will have to be adapted to your problem, e.g. by adding proper join conditions for the `entity_id`.

@Luuk pointed out that you don't need the end date because it can be derived from the data. This would be the case if you had entries for the start of "0 periods" as well, i.e. if there is no value set. If you don't have entries for these, you can't derive the end from the start of the respectively next period since there might be a gap in between.